# How to extract the links using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I extract the link in the following html:

```
<li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> <a href="https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf" rel="noopener" target="_blank">2021-2022 Common Data Set</a></li>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` and `css selectors` to get a list of links - Select all links that ends with `.pdf`:

```
[a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href$=".pdf"]')]
```

or more specific `<a>` with `href` as sibling of the `<i>` with class `fa-file-pdf`:

```
[a['href'] for a in soup.select('li i.fa-file-pdf + a[href]')]
```

---

So if the goal is to extract only the first:

```
link = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href$=".pdf"]')][0]
```

or

```
link = soup.select_one('a[href$=".pdf"]')['href']
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = '''
<li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> <a href="https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf" rel="noopener" target="_blank">2021-2022 Common Data Set</a></li>
<li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> <a href="https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf" rel="noopener" target="_blank">2021-2022 Common Data Set</a></li>
<li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> <a href="https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf" rel="noopener" target="_blank">2021-2022 Common Data Set</a></li>
<li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> <a href="https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf" rel="noopener" target="_blank">2021-2022 Common Data Set</a></li>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

urlList = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href$=".pdf"]')]
```

##### Output

```
['https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf',
 'https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf',
 'https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf',
 'https://manoa.hawaii.edu/miro/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/AnalysisBrief_CommonDataSet_2021.docx.pdf']
```

Comment: @Oasis101, it is common practice that if the solution solved your question that you mark the solution as accepted.